# Few SPIs at the same time as a bus?

Tags: spi, stm32, bus

According to http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1031/LN775/PF216846,

All STM32F1xx-series MCUs (and up) "offer standard communication interfaces (up to two I2Cs, three SPIs, one HDMI CEC, up to three USARTs and 2 UARTS)".

Is there a possibility to use more than one SPI line at same time to construct some kind of custom high-speed bus?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there are memory chips, etc. that use 2- and 4-lane SPI for greater throughput, but you can't just combine multiple single-lane controllers to get the same result, at least not easily. How much throughput do you need? A single SPI can run at up to 10-20 MHz easily, and with three controllers, you can have them all running at the same time to different devices.

Comment: Not sure how you would wire it up, but certainly its possible to use multiple SPI bus's in parallel to send more data, but I would advise against it since it could be very problematic.  Instead, think about what data rate you really need to use.  Many times you can use 1 SPI bus to send data at >1 Mbits/second which is sufficient for most needs.

Comment: Beyond the (quite fast) capabilities of the standard SPI bus, I'd wonder what an STM32 could do with that much data arriving/departing that quickly? Using standard parallel IO ports would seem the logical thing, like RAM buses with N data lines and N address/control lines.

Comment: Possible, yes. What's your actual purpose though?

Comment: The actual purpose is to build a maximum speed external interface for STM32-F1XX chips as most basic and hence  the cheapest in the line. There's also FSMC (http://www.emcu.it/STM32/STM32-TFT/STM32-TFT.html) module in models with more pins, but i`m not sure it's the fastest interface possible.

Comment: I think the problem you may have is keeping multiple data streams (the two or three MOSI lines) synchronized to the same clock. Assuming you start the SPI controllers one right after the other, there will be a clock cycle or more of delay between the MOSI edges. You'll need to slow down the clock to be sure that you still meet the timing requirements of all MOSI signals with respect to just one SPI clock.

Comment: If you can afford a chip with FSMC, and if your hardware can be coerced into adhering to one of the protocols implemented by the FSMC, then I suppose you can't beat it in terms of sheer throughput. Failing that, what about bit-banging? With one register write you can set/reset all 16 pins of one port (PA0,...,PA15 or PB0,...,PB15 or whatever) at once. If you code carefully in assembly you can probably get close to the max switching speed of the GPIOs using that scheme. Note that other peripherals must abide by that switching speed limitation as well, so that's the best you can do.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a hardware version of multithreading, is this correct? If so, dividing the data would do the trick.